# Go back in parser rows

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse a csv file with C# (using the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO library)
Although I can parse row fields using this method

```
fields = parser.ReadFields();
```

I would need to "go back" and read the same line again with this method:

```
 parser.ReadLine()
```

Is there a method to go back and read again the same line without parsing the whole file again?

Comment: You don't even mention the library you use to parse. Is it the `VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`?

Comment: Sorry, the library is Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to go back? This isn't a generic parser, it just parses well-formed CSV files. Its API produces the final result. You can't go back. If you want to check the previous line, you need to store it somewhere. If you need backtracking though, perhaps because the file contains unexpected headers, you probably need a better parser

Comment: @reds that's what the OP already uses. The method's documentation doesn't explain anything related to this problem

Comment: To make things simpler, I would need a reference to the entire line in the catch statement when an exception is thrown

Comment: @valbrux did you check the [ErrorLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorline(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ErrorLineNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorlinenumber(v=vs.110).aspx) properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much I have solved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common problem with fast forward-only parsers - you can't go back to check the content that caused a parsing error. That's why they are fast in the first place.

TextFieldParser raises a [MalformedLineException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.malformedlineexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in case of parsing errors. You can catch it and check the LineNumber property, or check the parser's  [ErrorLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorline(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ErrorLineNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorlinenumber(v=vs.110).aspx) properties.

In case of semantic errors, ie if the fields don't make sense, you'll have to use the input stream itself to find and load the original line.

If you use the TextFieldParser constructor that accepts a `Stream` object, you can keep track of the stream position befor and after each call to `ReadFields()`. If you detect a semantic error, you could change the stream's position to the one just before `ReadFields` and call `TextFieldParser.ReadLine()`, or just read a line from the stream with a StreamReader. For example:

```
try
{
    ...
    int pos=myStream.Position;
    var fields=parser.ReadFields();
    if (!fieldsOK(fields))
    {
        myStream.Seek(pos);
        var errorLine=parser.ReadLine();
        //Log it
    }
}
catch(MalformedLineException exc)
{
    var errorLine=parser.ErrorLine;
    //Log it
}
```

If you can't use a stream, or the stream is forward only, you may have to store the CSV data somewhere before parsing and reopen it to read the line. If your input is a file path for example, you can reload the file, move to the error line position and just read a line.

If you expect many semantic errors, it's best to collect error positions in a list so that you can read all relevant lines *after* you finish parsing the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the line again because the [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) uses a forward only stream and `ReadLine` *"returns the current line as a string and **advances the cursor to the next line**"*. The same happens with `ReadFields`.

But it's simple to store the line in a variable:

```
string line =  parser.ReadLine();
```

Now you can always access this line without reading it again.

If you need to access every line you've already read via index you have to fill a `List<string>`.

Comment: I need to use both method, because the first is to parse row and the second is to log any error during the parsing on a file

Comment: To make things simpler, I would need a reference to the entire line in the catch statement when an exception is thrown

Comment: You can access the line in the error-handler as Panagiotis has mentioned via [`ErrorLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.errorline(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 1):

The code below will handle the unescaped quotations while using the TextFieldParser ReadFields method:

```
string[] fields;

try {
    fields = parser.ReadFields();
}
catch (MalformedLineException ex) {
    string errorLine = parser.ErrorLine;
    string[] malformedFields = errorLine.Split(',');
    List<string> correctedFields = new List<string>();

    foreach (string field in malformedFields) {
        string correctedField = field.Replace("\"", "");
        correctedFields.Add(correctedField);
    }
    fields = correctedFields.ToArray();
}
```